# R chi squared test (3x2 contingency table) for each row in a table

Tags: r, chi-squared, contingency

I have a dataframe, and want to perform for each row (3x2 contingency table) a chi squared test .

- row 1 102    4998    105 3264    105 3636
- row 2 210    4890    22  3347    20  3721
- row 3 ...

So for the first row a chi squared test should be performed for the following contingency table;

- group A 102  4998
- group B 105  3264
- group C 105  3636

I use the following code, but this does not calculate the correct p-value (all p-values are equal to zero while this is not the case when I calculate the chi-square test myself):

```
table <- read.delim("dataframe.txt")
apply(table, 1, function(x) chisq.test(matrix(x,nrow=3)))
```

Could anyone help me with this?

Thank you in advance

Wannes

Comment: Are you confused about the row x col convention in R? Or are you confused about the fact that converting vectors to matrices assumes a column-major cosntructuion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ncol` instead of `nrow`:

```
apply(table, 1, function(x) chisq.test(matrix(x,ncol=3)))
```

Currently, you are building a matrix that looks like this for the first row:

```
102 3264
4998 105
105 3636
```

When R builds matrices from vectors, it builds them column-wise, so the second value goes into the second row, etc.

Also, if you want it to report just the p-value, you can do the following:

```
apply(table, 1, function(x) chisq.test(matrix(x,ncol=3))$p.value)
```

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated.